# CRM 2013 requirement gathering and expansion, Best Practices

Tags: entity, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, business-rules

I'm fairly new to CRM 2013, and I've been reading and watching a lot of videos on the subject. I'm hoping someone on the interweb, can offer some tips or suggestions that will resonate with the way I interpret and comprehend this material.

I have a regular MS Access DB, with a few different tables that is used to store personnel records. From what I've learned so far CRM looks like a good candidate for moving away from Access and towards CRM.

My question is, what are some best practices when it comes to gathering requirements and expanding them for the CRM 2013 environment?

i.e. (for simplicity sake)

MS Access db has two tables.

- Table A stores names of employees.
- Table B stores the employee's favorite food.

---

- Should each table have their own entity (Table_A 1:N, Table_B N:1), or are there times when you should combine multiple tables under a single entity?
- Is it considered bad form to just put everything under one entity?

  - If it is bad form, how do you determine when to split the information
    into multiple entities?
- Business processes seem to remind me of SharePoint workflows. When should you rely on a BP?

I hope this makes sense, I'm still trying to make sense of it all. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Dynamics CRM is backed by a SQL Server, so think in terms of SQL tables and what's better. Splitting into smaller objects which have single responsibility is is better in most cases, but this might affect the performance on joining records. Honestly, we are moving away from CRM in cloud because it's not scaleable, not reliable (if it goes down you need to wait when it goes up - no second replica), no control over underlying SQL data or SQL Server instance size (DTUs), hard to test, and is just painful for a big project. And we are going to replace all Business Processes with code, because they are not testable as well - you cannot write unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Although @sergeSemenov has some good points, you have to start what CRM was is.  CRM is a Customer Relationship Management suite, built on top of Xrm, a RADP, Rapid Application Development Platform.

Xrm is not designed to be the most flexible, most performant platform in the world.  If speed of use and the ability to use any specific technology/sever topology to meet your demand is a requirement for your app, don't start with XRM.

If speed of development, speed to market, reduced costs by having non developers doing work that in the custom app dev world are required by developers, or even a desire to be in the cloud on day 1, are more highly valued, then Xrm, and consequently CRM is a great place to start.

As far as your questions, it all depends.  The more normalized your data is, multiple entities for each relationship, the less work involved in ensuring they are all in sync, but usually the more difficult it is for your end users to work with the information.  They'll have to navigate to multiple forms for data entry, and have lots of joins to configure in reports.

I generally try to keep the data as normalized as possible, but if anything is a 1:1 relationship, combine that into single entity.  Or you know it's going to be a 1:2 or 1:3 relationship (See addresses on contacts and accounts for example)

Basically, it is an answer that requires a unique look at the application requirements, and personal experience.  I would highly recommend seeking a consultant with CRM experience.  Another advantage of a platform, is that there is a whole resource pool of developers, and BAs that already know the framework, and can provide value to the business on day one, rather than taking 2 or 3 weeks getting up to speed on your specific architecture.

Good luck!